# AutoMapper not Populating Data

Tags: c#, orm, automapper

I have an automapper setup that is not returning an error.  It returns the class as intended but the properties are not populated.  I have checked the reader coming in and the data is there.

This is a Web API Core project using async methods.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Student.cs

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WebAPI.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        public string StudentFirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string StudentLastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public static async Task<Student> GetStudentByID(string conn, int StudentID)
        {
            var ret = new Student();

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
            {
                var cmd = new SqlCommand("Core.StudentByID_Get", connection);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("StudentID", StudentID);
                await connection.OpenAsync();
                using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        ret = ModelUtils.InitializeAutomapper().Map<Student>(reader);
                    }
                }

            }

            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

ModelUtils.cs

```
using AutoMapper;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WebAPI.Models
{
    public class ModelUtils
    {
       public static Mapper InitializeAutomapper()
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<SqlDataReader, Student>();
            });

            var mapper = new Mapper(config);
            return mapper;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would never understand or encourage the use of automapper

Comment: What would you recommend?

Comment: directly mapping, take less effort, more organization, in the end, less time.

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preference in this situation would not be to use AutoMapper, but to use Dapper ORM to wrap the data access, something like:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var student = await connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<Student>(
        "Core.StudentByID_Get",
        param: new { StudentID },
        commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}
```

Which would do the mapping to a Student object for you.

(I'd also separate the data access out into its own class, leaving the Student class simply containing the three properties.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this.  Simple and will save dozens of lines of code per class that is largely boilerplate.